# HTML TOC does not work on page refresh

Tags: html, tapestry, tableofcontents

I'm setting up a simple HTML TOC which scrolls to the correct content id while clicking a url like this `<a href="#example_toc">Example TOC</a>`. The TOC appends to the url like so

`https://www.example.com/#example_toc`

Now if I refresh the browser with the TOC appended the url, it doesn't scroll to the content. What could possible break this?

I'm generating the HTML using Tapestry5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had an autofocus to a search box.